# Email tracked when sender opens the email

Tags: email, tracking

I am working on tracking emails using pixel image. It is tracking the email and increasing the read count when the receiver is opening the email.

The issue is, it is also tracking the email and increasing the read count when the sender is opening the email.

What should I do so that the email is tracked only when the receiver opens the email?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A sender can open an email which normally gets saved in his/her Sent folder.

Suppose an email is send by a sender. Then a copy of this email would normally be saved in `Sent` folder of sender. Now, a copy of email is saved in Sent folder via `IMAP` or proprietary `WebMail or Mobile Application`. You can easily embed appropriate pixel image in email when it gets saved in Sent folder via WebMail or Mobile Application because you yourself create the email MIME. When email is saved in Sent folder via IMAP, then you might need to parse the email MIME and embed appropriate pixel image in email which is send by IMAP Client to be saved in Sent folder.

*Modifying the email saved in folder via IMAP Client is normally not done.

Comment: But how will this help me in achieving my goal? I am embedding the pixel image before sending the email.

Comment: Use different pixel image (say, image_a) for email which receiver would receive and a different pixel image (say image_b) for email which would get saved in Sent folder. Now you can track access of image_a and image_b separately.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this one? any code samples?

Comment: @Ravi First of all, let know whether you are an email provider or a normal user sending a email. Because all of the things mentioned in my post can be done at email provider side. Normal user can just embed a pixel image in an email which will both, get saved in sent folder of sender and the same email would be received by  recipient.